# Fn+f7 key is not working

Tags: linux, laptop, keyboard, asus-laptop, fn-key

Keybinding fn+f7? which previously switched screen backlight, stopped working after kernel update 4.20 on my laptop Asus X540SA. Can I get it back?

Comment: What Linux distribution (name and version) are you using? Do you know which package is used for brightness control? Can you change the brightness via `/sys/class/backlight/`?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev
1. Arch;
2. Nope, but for changing brightness via fn+f5 or fn+f6 I use xbacklight;
3. Yes